# Getting distinct enum values C++

Tags: c++, enums

I'm trying to get a distinct value from my enumeration using void pointers.

I've an enum declaration of a list of animals

```
enum Animal {Rat, Ox, Tiger, Rabbit, Dragon, Snake, Horse, Sheep, Monkey, Rooster, Dog, Pig};
```

So firstly, i have a function that returns me a value from my enumeration randomly

```
VoidPtr getAnAnimal()
{
   VoidPtr anAnimal;

   Animal *a = new Animal;

   int k = rand() % 12;

   *a = static_cast<Animal>(k);

   anAnimal = a;

   return anAnimal;
}
```

Then during my construction of array, I've a conditional statement that states if the array has the same value, it is suppose to randomly generate another enum value

```
void constructSet(VoidPtr* animalArray, int size)
 { 

   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       animalArray[i] = getAnAnimal();

        int k = 0; 

       while ((k < i) && (animalArray[i] == animalArray[k]))
       {     
           animalArray[i] = getAnAnimal();   

           k++;
       }        
   }

}
```

Unfortunately, it still returns me the same enum value despite calling for another value if the array are the same.

Comment: One can not cast an integer to an object - you would also have a memory leak here as the new Animal (a) is lost without being deleted

Comment: You probably want to use a factory function based on your `enum`. Some casting will be needed. And use `Animal*` instead of `VoidPtr`.

Comment: I think what you're trying to do is make an animal factory - where you call getAnimal(AnimalTypeEnum) ... It's called a factory pattern ... grr - beaten to the punch by @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: If you are trying to make sure you have no repeats in the whole set, I think you are on the wrong track.  This seems to get another animal to prevent two of the same kind in a row, but not duplicates elsewhere in the sequence.  Maybe I'm reading too much into how you see distinct

Comment: Well, I see an edit address my comment above.  But you still might want to put a `delete animalArray[i];` before the `animalArray[i] = getAnAnimal()` in your while loop.  Ownership of the Animals in animalArray is effectively passing to the call of `constructSet()` apparently

Comment: @UKMonkey you can, if your class has a constructor that accepts an integer. But this code does look quite odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is that when comparing  `animalArray[i]==animalArray[k]` you compare the addresses of the enums not their value. The proper comparison would be (edited after comment, obviously this is not what clean code looks like, but the mistake lies in passing the `enum` as a `void*`)

```
*static_cast<Animal*>(animalArray[i])==*static_cast<Animal*>(animalArray[k])
```

However, you should reconsider storing your `Animal` as pointer.
In C++ there is usually no reason to allocate objects by `new` (neither do you need to work with pointers in C++, unless you really have to). At least not for simple problems as yours.

Comment: when i try to dereference my pointer array it says `void is not a pointer-to-object type`

Comment: You are right. You'd also first need to cast `animalArray[i]` to `Animal*` -- **but that whole design idea of passing `enum` values as pointers is broken!**

Answer (score -1):

Your algorithm in `constructSet` does not really correspond to your description.

> I've a conditional statement that states if the array has the same
>   value, it is suppose to randomly generate another enum value

The two instructions `animalArray[i] = getAnimal();` and `k++` should be in different branches of a condition. `k++` should iterate while the `animalArray[i]` is different from `animalArray[k]`. Suppose for example that `*animalArray[i] != *animalArray[0]` but `*animalArray[i] == *animalArray[1]` you will insert it even if the array has a same value.

Moreover `k` should be reinitialized each time a new animal is inserted.

Here is a possible alternative algorithm. I have not checked for the compilation errors.

```
void constructSet(VoidPtr* animalArray, int size)
 {
   int attempt = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       animalArray[i] = getAnAnimal();
       int k = 0;  
       while ((k < i) && (*reinterpret_cast<const Animal*>(animalArray[i]) != *reinterpret_cast<const Animal*>(animalArray[k])))
           k++;
       if (k < i && attempt < 12) { // retry?
           --i;
           ++attempt;
       }
       else // accept the animal
          attempt = 0;
   }
}
```